# Will scaling images at runtime impact my game's speed?

Tags: java, 2d, android, image, scale

I have read the android developer guide to working on different screen sizes. My question is, **if I only provide one image in the drawable file, and let android scale it for me, will it impact the overall performance of my app?**

For example, I am simply displaying a red square, and there aren't any details to the square. Should I provide alternative resources, will android's scaling impact my performance as an app on bigger/smaller screens?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is due to memory usage, wasted memory bandwidth and/or the time it takes to rescale it to the proper size at load time.

In the case of Android using the 2D UI the image will be scaled once to the proper size at load time but this takes a bit of time and the larger original will be kept in memory if a reference to it is kept.

In the case of direct OpenGL draw calls without mipmaps drawing a large image by scaling it down on the fly forces the GPU to fetch a lot of unused pixel from memory. An image that is twice as big as it needs to be (2x width, 2x height) will take 4x the memory bandwidth.

Comment: On estimate, what would the maximum time be to scale the image. My square is `52x52` and it is in the `drawable` directory? Because I'm debating to even go through the hassle of re-sizing all of my images 36 times...

Comment: One image at 52x52 should not be perceptible. It can become an issue with sizes 512x512 and above depending on number of texture. It's all a question of quantity vs device speed and memory.

Comment: But won't scaling a 52x52 image up to xxxhdpi be an issue

Comment: Actually, that'll speed up things as the scaling will be done on the fly by the GPU and this reduces memory bandwidth compared to a native 1:1 size. The only issue will be if the image is interpolated the edges of your square will be blurred.

Comment: Ok, that's great, so I won't have any alternative drawable resources! What about background? Will having one background image slow it down? It is ok if the background gets a little blurred, I am more worried about the speed...please let me know